# Образование словосочетания

Tags: словосочетания

> Словосочетание — это два слова, связанные между собой по смыслу. В
>   словосочетании одно слово зависит от другого. Подлежащее и сказуемое
>   не образуют словосочетания. В предложении: девочка пела веселую
>   песенку — два словосочетания: пела песенку, песенку веселую.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что словосочетания образуются между второстепенными и главными членами, и между второстепенными, если они связаны по смыслу?

Например:

В субботу наш класс ездил в зоопарк.
класс — подлежащее.
класс (что делал?) ездил — сказуемое.
класс (чей?) наш — втор. ч. пояс. подл.
ездил (куда?) в зоопарк — втор. ч. пояс. сказ.
ездил (когда?) в субботу — втор. ч. пояс. сказ.

Словосочетания: наш класс, ездил в зоопарк, ездил в субботу.

Там живут животные из разных стран мира. (правильно ли поставил вопросы?)
(кто?) животные — подлежащее
животные (что делают?) живут — сказуемое
животные (откуда?) из стран — втор. ч. пояс. подл.
из стран (каких?) разных — втор. ч. пояс. втор. ч.
из стран (чего?) мира — втор. ч. пояс. втор. ч.
живут (где?) там — втор. ч. пояс. сказ.

Словосочетания: там живут, животные из стран, животные из стран мира, животные из разных стран, животные из разных стран мира, из стран мира, из разных стран.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Словосочетание (грамматическая справка):**

В грамматике выделяют три синтаксические (грамматические) единицы: **слово, словосочетание, предложение.** Слова и словосочетания имеют назывную функцию (называют признаки, предметы, действия), а предложение ― это уже сообщение о предметах и явлениях, соотнесенное со  временем и модальностью (реальное, нереальное, желаемое действие).

Итак, **словосочетание ― это сочетание двух (или более) слов, связанных грамматической подчинительной связью** (главное слово + зависимое слово). Словосочетания входят в состав предложения, а за его пределами могут служить названиями, указателями и т.д.

2) Вы правильно делаете разбор, **но в ваших рассуждениях есть неточность**:  предложения **составляются** из словосочетаний (или предложение можно **разложить** на словосочетания), но **словосочетания не могут образовываться** "между второстепенными и главными членами..."

Двусоставные предложения включают подлежащее и сказуемое, между ними существует особая (предикативная связь). В распространенном предложении мы выделяем второстепенные члены, составляющие **группу подлежащего и сказуемого**. Эти группы можно разложить на словосочетания (простые и распространенные).

Например:Там живут //животные из разных стран мира. 
Группа подлежащего ― это распространенное словосочетание, состоящее из трех простых: животные из стран,  из стран мира, из разных стран.

Comment: Я школьник. Это из программы 3 класса. Очень сложно написали, но спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, но тогда запомните хотя бы одну вещь: сочетания не образуются в предложении, наоборот, предложение составляют из словосочетаний или из имеющегося предложения выделяют словосочетания.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо!